# Filling sourrounding cells in a 3D vector

Tags: vector, 3d, nearest-neighbor

I need to fill a 3d vector in a way that, once x,y,z are fixed, the code has to write numbers in all the nearest neighbours (i.e. all the cells with x+/-1, y+/-1, z+/-1). Of course I don't want the cells outside the boundaries to be filler. So far I've tried the following approach

```
void setSphericalSource(int x, int y, int z, float sigma, vector<vector<vector<float>>>& vec, float maxAct) {

float total_activity = 0.0;
vec[z][y][x] = maxAct ; //hotspot
total_activity += maxAct;

if (x > 0 && x < vec[0][0].size() && y > 0 && y < vec[0].size() && z > 0 && z < vec.size()) {
    
    //cells with face in common
    vec[z][y][x + 1] = maxAct/2;
    vec[z][y][x - 1] = maxAct/2;
    vec[z][y + 1][x] = maxAct/2;
    vec[z][y - 1][x] = maxAct/2;
    vec[z + 1][y][x] = maxAct/2;
    vec[z - 1][y][x] = maxAct/2;


    //cells with edge in common
    vec[z][y + 1][x + 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z][y + 1][x - 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z][y - 1][x + 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z][y - 1][x - 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z + 1][y][x + 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z + 1][y][x - 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z - 1][y][x + 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z - 1][y][x - 1] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z + 1][y + 1][x] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z + 1][y - 1][x] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z - 1][y + 1][x] = maxAct/3;
    vec[z - 1][y - 1][x] = maxAct/3;


    //cells with a vertex in common
    vec[z + 1][y + 1][x + 1] = maxAct/4;
    vec[z + 1][y + 1][x - 1] = maxAct/4;
    vec[z + 1][y - 1][x - 1] = maxAct/4;
    vec[z - 1][y - 1][x - 1] = maxAct/4;
    vec[z + 1][y - 1][x + 1] = maxAct/4;
    vec[z - 1][y + 1][x + 1] = maxAct/4;
    vec[z - 1][y - 1][x + 1] = maxAct/4;
    vec[z - 1][y + 1][x - 1] = maxAct/4;

}
```

}

In practice I first check if x,y,z belong to the inner part of the 3d vector, then I go to the external cells and so on until a spherical volume around the chosen center is filled (skipping the cells that exceed the boundaries).

The problem rises when I want to set a spherical source with the center on a face, on an edge or on a vertex of the 3D grid. Is there a better way than repeating the code above for each face, each vertex and each corner?

Comment: Before you ask for _a more efficient way of obtaining the same result_, you should seek to obtain the correct result; the shown approach doesn't handle the cases where y or z or more than one of x, y, z lie on a boundary.

Comment: I have fixed the code in a way that it works. Unfortunately I could not think of an efficient method to fill a spherical contour of the center when the center is on a face, an edge or a corner.

Comment: The _fixed_ code now exceeds the upper vector bound if x, y or z lie on an upper boundary.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of repeating the code above for each face, each vertex and each corner?

I take you actually meant "Is there a better way **than** repeating the code above for each face, each vertex and each corner?" - Here is another way; it's up to the reader to judge whether it's better:

```
    for (int k = -1; k <= 1; ++k)
    for (int j = -1; j <= 1; ++j)
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1; ++i)
    {
        int d = abs(i)+abs(j)+abs(k)+1;
        x += i, y += j, z += k;
        if (0 <= x && x < vec[0][0].size()
         && 0 <= y && y < vec[0]   .size()
         && 0 <= z && z < vec      .size()
           ) vec[z][y][x] = maxAct/d;
        x -= i, y -= j, z -= k;
    }
```

Comment: Wrote the message in a rush and did not check the text, my bad.